# Working percentage in c#

Tags: c#, math

I have two values one with a decimal value
and another value with a value which will calculate the percentage of that decimal value
for example:

> 60 % of 10 = 6

```
decimal value1 = 10;
decimal percentage = 60;
textbox1.text = ("mathsum here").toString();
```

How would you calculate this value using the decimal value and value containing the percentage value?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
number * percentage / 100
```

so

```
10 * 60 / 100 = 6
```

Comment: how would you work 100% of the value? sounds daft because it will be the value anyway but won't compile when inputting 100?

Comment: You should probably put `m` after those numbers just to be clear. `10 * 60 / 100` may work as integers, but `45 * 2 / 100` wouldn't.

Comment: @question21: it's correct: 100% of 527 is 527 * 100 / 100 = 527

Comment: @question21: You must have made a mistake. `10 * 100 / 100` will definitely come out to `10`.

Answer (score 7):

Maybe it will help you to think of it in this way.

```
6
-- = .6 (or equivalent to your 60%)
10
```

In your example you'd like to know how to calculate the numerator (the 6) so assign a variable to it.  Let's use X.

```
X
-- = .6
10
```

.. and solve for X by multiplying both sides by 10 (in your case).

```
X * 10 = .6 * 10
------
  10

X = .6 * 10
```

From this I hope you can see that you can take your percentage value and multiply it by your 'decimal' value.

Note that in order to get the .6 you will need to convert your percentage (60) by dividing it by 100.

So our final formula is:

```
60
--- * 10
100
```

or using your variables:

```
percentage
---------- * value1
   100
```

I hope I've added to your understanding even if my formula is similar to the previous answers.  I wanted to make sure you understood how the formula was derived.

Good luck!

Answer (score 5):

```
var result = (percentage/100) * value1;
textbox1.Text = result.ToString();
```

Answer (score 4):

You mean like this?

```
textbox1.text = (value1 * percentage/100).ToString();
```

By the way, `toString` is written `ToString` in C# with a capital **T**.

Answer (score 3):

```
var answer = value1 * (percentage/100);
```

Comment: Declare *percentage* as an int to see this code fail badly.  Don't use unnecessary parentheses.

Answer (score 3):

To get the percentage amount

```
decimal Value = 1200;
int percentage = 20; //20%

var result=(percentage/100)*(Value);
```

Answer (score 2):

Wouldn't this just be

```
percentage/100m*value
```

?

Answer (score 1):

I would separate the concerns:

1. Calculate a portion of your original decimal:

   decimal result = (value * percentage) / 100.0;
2. Provide an appropriate formatter to output the result as a percentage:

   text = result.ToString("0.0%");

http://www.dotnetperls.com/percentage

Answer (score 1):

from question it self answer is clear

60% means 60/100 then calculate it with the value

60 / 100 * 10 = 6  use the logic for variables

```
 textbox1.Text = ((percentage /100) * value).ToString();
```

or

```
 textbox1.Text = ((percentage * .01 ) * value).ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to divide by 100.

60% = 60/100.